# How to get to an empty previously created Firebase document

Tags: swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I made a notification system in the application, i.e. a user likes an entry and is sent a blank document. For the notification system to work correctly I had to use this particular method.  How can I access this record in the future if the notification is deleted? If a blank document has been created.

```
class TweetActionViewModels: ObservableObject {
    let tweet: Tweet
    @Published var didLike = false
    @Published var didSaved = false
    @EnvironmentObject var viewModel : AuthViewModel
    
    
    init(tweet: Tweet) {
        self.tweet = tweet
        self.tweetLikes = tweet.likes
        checkIfUserLikedTweet()
        checkIfUserSave()
    }
    
    @Published var tweetLikes: Int
    
    func likeTweet() {
        let newValue = tweet.likes + 1
               guard let uid = AuthViewModel.shared.userSession?.uid else { return }
               let tweetLikesRef = COLLECTION_TWEETS.document(tweet.id).collection("tweet-likes")
               let userLikesRef = COLLECTION_USERS.document(uid).collection("user-likes")
        // ...
        COLLECTION_TWEETS.document(tweet.id).updateData(["likes": newValue]) { _ in
            tweetLikesRef.document(uid).setData([:]) { _ in // Set the user ID as the document ID
                userLikesRef.document(uid).setData([:]) { _ in
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        self.sendNotification(for: self.tweet.uid, caption: self.tweet.caption, tweetId: self.tweet.id)
                        self.didLike = true
                        self.tweetLikes += 1
                        ProgressHUD.dismiss()
                        self.objectWillChange.send()
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    
    
    func sendNotification(for userId: String, caption: String, tweetId: String) {
        guard let users = AuthViewModel.shared.user else { return }
        
//        guard let userCheck = AuthViewModel.shared.user?.isCurrentUser else { return }
        
        
        
        
        if users.id == userId {
            
        } else {
            
            let uid = tweet.uid
            
            let docRef = COLLECTION_USERS.document(uid).collection("notifications-tweets").document()
            
            let data: [String:Any] = ["uid": users.id,
                                      "tweet" : userId,
                                      "caption": caption,
                                      "timestamp": Timestamp(date: Date()),
                                      "username": users.username,
                                      "profileImageUrl": users.profileImageUrl,
                                      "id": tweetId]
            
            docRef.setData(data) { _ in
                print("DEBUG: Succesfully sended notfication")
            }
        }
    }
    

    
    func unlikeTweet() {
        let newValue = tweet.likes - 1
        guard let uid = AuthViewModel.shared.userSession?.uid else { return }
        let tweetLikesRef = COLLECTION_TWEETS.document(tweet.id).collection("tweet-likes")
        let userLikesRef = COLLECTION_USERS.document(uid).collection("user-likes")

        COLLECTION_TWEETS.document(tweet.id).updateData(["likes": newValue]) { _ in
            tweetLikesRef.document(uid).delete { _ in
                userLikesRef.document(self.tweet.id).delete { _ in
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        self.didLike = false
                        self.tweetLikes -= 1
                        self.deleteNotification(userTo: self.tweet.uid)
                        ProgressHUD.dismiss() // закрытие индикатора загрузки
                        self.objectWillChange.send()
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
    func deleteNotification(userTo: String) {
        let uid = userTo

        let docRef = COLLECTION_USERS.document(uid).collection("notifications-tweets").document(uid)

        docRef.delete() { error in
            if let error = error {
                print("Error delete tweet \(error)")
            } else {
                print("Tweetnotif succesfully removed")
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: What is the purpose of sending a blank document? Also, why not just delete the document when the notification is deleted?